# Some issues with Python regex findall

Tags: python, regex, string

Got string source :

```
string ="""
html,, 
    head,,        profile http://gmpg.org/xfn/11 ,,
                  lang en-US ,,

        title,,   Some markright page.
        ,,title
    ,,head
"""
```

...which have to parse as html :

```
<html>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" lang="en-US">
<title>Some markright page</title>
</head>
```

I want to parse it with one `re.findall` pass like :

```
tagList = re.findall( 
    r'\s*([A-Z]?[a-z]+[0-9]?,,){1}'   # Opening tag - has to be one
    r'(.* ,,)*'                       # Attributes - could be more than one
    r'(.*)?'                          # Content - could be one
    r'(\s+,,[a-z]+[0-9]?)?'           # Ending tag - could be one
    , string )#, flags=re.S )  # can't make any use of DOTALL flag   

for t in tagList :
    n=0
    for s in t :
        n+=1
        print "String group No:"+str(n)+" -> ", s.strip()
    print "_"*10
```

...but got only:

```
String group No:1 ->  html,,
String group No:2 ->  
String group No:3 ->  
String group No:4 ->  
__________
String group No:1 ->  head,,
String group No:2 ->  profile http://gmpg.org/xfn/11 ,,
String group No:3 ->  
String group No:4 ->  
__________
String group No:1 ->  title,,
String group No:2 ->  
String group No:3 ->  Some markright page.
String group No:4 ->  ,,title
```

Please, keep in mind that I **have** to make my own parser, and upper mentioned problem is just one appliance of this markup superset so help if you can & want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I will do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

pat = re.compile(r'''
    (?P<open> \b [^\W_]+ ) ,, |
    ,, (?P<close> [^\W_]+ ) \b |
    (?P<attrName> \S+ ) [ ] (?P<attrValue> [^,\n]+ ) [ ] ,, |
    (?P<textContent> [^,\s] (?: [^,] | , (?!,) )*? ) \s* (?=[^\W_]*,,)''',
      re.X)

txt = '''html,, 
    head,,        profile http://gmpg.org/xfn/11 ,,
                  lang en-US ,,

        title,,   Some markright page.
        ,,title
    ,,head'''

result = ''
opened = False
for m in pat.finditer(txt):
    if m.group('attrName'):
        result += ' ' + m.group('attrName') + '="' + m.group('attrValue') + '"'
    else:
        if opened:
            opened = False
            result += '>'
        if m.group('open'):
            result += '<' + m.group('open')
            opened = True
        elif m.group('close'):
            result += '</' + m.group('close') + '>'
        else:
            result += m.group('textContent')
print result
```

Note: I assume that the text content is always enclosed between tags.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, it's indeed useful with named captures to make a long pattern more readable. However the way you wrotes your pattern is possible too, and is used in Java that doesn't have an heredoc syntax.

Comment: Text content works like a charm even if I put some text formatting tags like: title,, Some b,, markright ,,b page. ,,title ...so it should be OK.

Comment: @Alex: About that, I have changed the lookahead form `(?=,,)` to `(?=[^\W_]*,,)` to stop the text content part at the first encountered tag.

Comment: please can you help me with one detail. Can you show me how to define attribute names and values "with anything except double commas", because it fails with single comma like : feoffset,,  dx 2,5 ,,  ,,feoffset. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex: You have several ways. You can change this part `(?P<attrValue> [^,\n]+ ) [ ] ,,` with `(?P<attrValue> (?s).*? ) [ ] ,,` *(using a lazy quantifier)*, or you can stay with a greedy quantifiers with `(?P<attrValue> (?:[^,\n]|,(?!,))* ) [ ] ,,`. Note that contrary to the original answer, empty attributes are now allowed.